# Retorno inesperado ao converter String para Inteiro no Java

Tags: java, arduino, swingworker

Tenho um codigo java no qual recebe dados de rotacao do motor. No java com recebo uma String necessito converter para inteiro para fazer uma comparacao para saber se o motor ligou ou nao. Quando recebo a string dou print na tela e aparece corretamente o valor, porem na conversao para o inteiro so recebe o valor null, porque sera que a String esta correta mas quando converte me rtorna null, tem outro metodo de conversao?

Segue o codigo:

```
package tanio;

import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class obterrpm extends SwingWorker {

    public SerialVirtualCom3 arduino6;
     String valorrpm;
     int valorrpmint;


    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {

         SerialVirtualCom3  arduino6 = new SerialVirtualCom3("COM3", 9600,0);

        arduino6.receberDados();



        while(true){
        delay.delay(300);
        valorrpm = arduino6.getPeso();
        //System.out.println(valorrpm); //printa o valor corretamente
        valorrpmint = Integer.parseInt(valorrpm); //conversao para o int

        System.out.println(valorrpmint); //retorno e null
        //chamarTelaPrincipal.rpm.setText(String.format("%s",arduino6.getPeso()));
        //chamarTelaPrincipal.rpm.setText(String.format("%s", valorrpmint));





    }



    }   
}
```

[image: rotacao recebida do arduino]
[image: rotacao no programa java com a variavel nao convertida]

[image: variavel convertida nao aparece nada]

SerialVirtualCom3

```
package tanio;

import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.NoSuchPortException;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;


public class SerialVirtualCom3  implements Runnable, SerialPortEventListener { 


    public String Dadoslidos; 

    public int nodeBytes; 

    private int baudrate; 

    private int timeout; 

    private CommPortIdentifier cp; 

    private SerialPort porta; 

    private OutputStream saida; 

    private InputStream entrada; 

    private Thread threadLeitura; 

    private boolean IDPortaOK;

    private boolean PortaOK; 

    private boolean Leitura; 

    private boolean Escrita;

    private String Porta; 

    protected String peso;

    public char valorlido;


    public void setPeso(String peso){

        this.peso = peso;

}



public String getPeso(){

        return peso;

}


public SerialVirtualCom3( String p , int b , int t ){

    this.Porta = p;

    this.baudrate = b;

    this.timeout = t;

}

public void HabilitarEscrita(){

    Escrita = true;

    Leitura = false;

}



public void HabilitarLeitura(){

    Escrita = false;

    Leitura = true;

}






///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///*
public void ObterIdDaPorta(){

                try {
                cp = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(Porta);

                if ( cp != null ) {

    //              System.out.println("Sucesso");


                    IDPortaOK = true; 

        //            ligado = 0;
            //        desligado = 1;

                }
                }

            /*
                IDPortaOK = false;
                ligado = 1;
                desligado = 0;
                //ligado = 1;
                //desligado = 0
                }
                */          
            catch (NoSuchPortException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

                //System.out.println("Nao ha Conexao!");
              //  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Houve um erro na Conexão!\nVerifique o cabo usb!");
                //teste de tratamento desta excessao

                //ligado = 1;
                //desligado = 0;
                //ObterIdDaPorta();
                //IDPortaOK = false;


            }
        }



//*/

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/*

public void ObterIdDaPorta(){

    boolean flag = false;

//  while (flag == false ){

        try {

        cp = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(Porta);

        if ( cp == null ) {

            System.out.println("Erro na porta");

            IDPortaOK = false;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Houve um erro na Conexão!\nVerifique o cabo usb!");
           // FecharCom();

            //ObterIdDaPorta();

            //System.exit(1);

        }

        IDPortaOK = true;
 //       flag = true;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        //System.out.println("Erro obtendo ID da porta: " + e);

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Houve um erro na Conexão!\nVerifique o cabo usb!");
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Houve um erro na Conexão!");
        IDPortaOK = false;
        //FecharCom();
        //flag = false;


        //ObterIdDaPorta();
        //System.exit(1);
    }
    }
  //  }
//}
//}



*/

/*
public void AbrirPorta(){

    try {


        porta = (SerialPort)cp.open("SerialComLeitura", timeout);

        PortaOK = true;

        //configurar parâmetros

        porta.setSerialPortParams(baudrate,

        porta.DATABITS_8,

        porta.STOPBITS_1,

        porta.PARITY_NONE);

        porta.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_NONE);

    }catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
        //PortaOK = false;

        //System.out.println("Erro abrindo comunicação: " + e);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Houve um erro na Conexão!\nVerifique o cabo usb!");
        FecharCom();

        //System.exit(1);

    }

}

*/







        public void AbrirPorta(){



               try {

                porta = (SerialPort)cp.open("SerialComLeitura", timeout);

                if (porta != null) {


                //configurar parâmetros

                porta.setSerialPortParams(baudrate,

                porta.DATABITS_8,

                porta.STOPBITS_1,

                porta.PARITY_NONE);

                porta.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_NONE);

              //  System.out.println("Sucesso no tratamento do erro de abrir porta!");

                PortaOK = true;



                }
    }
            catch(Exception e){


                e.printStackTrace();

                //System.out.println("houve um erro ao tratar a excessao do abrir porta!");
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Houve um erro na Conexão!\nVerifique o cabo usb!");
                //teste de tratamento desta excessao

                //ligado = 1;
                //desligado = 0;
                //FecharCom();
                //ObterIdDaPorta();
                //AbrirPorta();

                //ObterIdDaPorta();
                //AbrirPorta();
                //IDPortaOK = false;


                /*
                e.printStackTrace();
                //PortaOK = false;

                //System.out.println("Erro abrindo comunicação: " + e);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Houve um erro na Conexão!\nVerifique o cabo usb!");
                FecharCom();
                */
                //System.exit(1);

            }

        }






























public void LerDados(){

    if (Escrita == false){

        try {

            entrada = porta.getInputStream();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
             //System.out.println("Erro de stream: " + e);
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Houve um erro na Conexão!\nVerifique o cabo usb!");
            //FecharCom();
            //AbrirPorta();
            //LerDados();
          //  System.exit(1);

        }

        try {

            porta.addEventListener(this);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            //System.out.println("Erro de listener: " + e);
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Houve um erro na Conexão!\nVerifique o cabo usb!");
            //FecharCom();
          //  AbrirPorta();
        //    LerDados();
            //System.exit(1);

        }

        porta.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);

        try {

            threadLeitura = new Thread(this);

            threadLeitura.start();

           run();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //System.out.println("Erro de Thred: " + e);
         //   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Houve um erro na Conexão!\nVerifique o cabo usb!");
           // FecharCom();
            //AbrirPorta();
            //LerDados();
        }

    }

}

public void escrever(int msg){

    if (Escrita==true) {

        try {

            saida = porta.getOutputStream();

            //System.out.println("FLUXO OK!");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           System.out.println("Erro.STATUS: " + e );
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Houve um erro na Conexão!\nVerifique o cabo usb!\nReconecte o Cabo e Aguarde alguns segundos!");
            //FecharCom();

            //enviarDados(msg);
        }

        try {

            //System.out.println("Enviando um byte para " + Porta );

            //System.out.println("Enviando : " + msg );

            saida.write(msg);

            Thread.sleep(100);

            saida.flush();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //System.out.println("Houve um erro durante o envio. ");

            System.out.println("STATUS: " + e );
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Houve um erro na Conexão!\nVerifique o cabo usb!");
            //FecharCom();
            //System.exit(1);

        }

    } else {

       // System.exit(1);
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Houve um erro na Conexão!\nVerifique o cabo usb!");
        //FecharCom();
    }

}

public void run(){

    try {

        Thread.sleep(5);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        //System.out.println("Erro de Thred: " + e);
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Houve um erro na Conexão!\nVerifique o cabo usb!");
        //FecharCom(); 
        //run();
    }

}

public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent ev){        

    StringBuffer bufferLeitura = new StringBuffer();

    int novoDado = 0;



    switch (ev.getEventType()) {

        case SerialPortEvent.BI:

        case SerialPortEvent.OE:

        case SerialPortEvent.FE:

        case SerialPortEvent.PE:

        case SerialPortEvent.CD:

        case SerialPortEvent.CTS:

        case SerialPortEvent.DSR:

        case SerialPortEvent.RI:

        case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:

        break;

        case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:

            //Novo algoritmo de leitura.

            while(novoDado != -1){

                try{

                    novoDado = entrada.read();

                    if(novoDado == -1){

                        break;

                    }

                    if('\r' == (char)novoDado){

                        bufferLeitura.append('\n');

                    }else{

                        bufferLeitura.append((char)novoDado);

                    }

                }catch(IOException ioe){

                   // System.out.println("Erro de leitura serial: " + ioe);
          //          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Houve um erro na Conexão!\nVerifique o cabo usb!");

                }

            }

            setPeso(new String(bufferLeitura));

            //System.out.println(getPeso());



        break;

    }

}

public void FecharCom(){

    try {

        porta.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     //   System.out.println("Erro fechando porta: " + e);
      //  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Houve um erro na Conexão!\nVerifique o cabo usb!");
       // FecharCom();
//        System.exit(0);

    }

}

public String obterPorta(){

    return Porta;

}



public int obterBaudrate(){

    return baudrate;

}



public void enviarDados(int msg)
{
    HabilitarEscrita();


    ObterIdDaPorta();

    AbrirPorta();

    escrever(msg);


    FecharCom();
}


String receberDados(){

    HabilitarLeitura();
    ObterIdDaPorta();
    AbrirPorta();
    LerDados();
    return getPeso();
}


}
```

Comment: Não é possível que o `System.out.println(valorrpmint);` mostre `null`. Você pode postar a sua saída para darmos uma olhada nela?

Comment: Victor, desculpe, com null eu quis dizer que nao retorna nada, o programa roda porem nao a retorno se eu usar valorrpmint. com o variavel sem conversao, arduino6.getPeso(que e uma string) o valor e printado na tela normalmente. Porque sera que o resultado vazio?

Comment: Ele mostra zero?

Comment: Nao, nada, na Saida normal, com a variavel valorrpm, o valor do rpm e printado na tela corretamente, Porem com a valorrpmint nao aparece nada, fica so nisso:                                                                    
            WARNING:  RXTX Version mismatch
 Jar version = RXTX-2.2pre1
 native lib Version = RXTX-2.2pre2

Comment: Manda o que o seu arduino está mostrando. Da um print(valorrpm) e manda pra gente.

Comment: Tente mover a declaração de `valorrpm` e `valorrpmint` para dentro do escopo do método `doInBackground`. Feito isso, para ter certeza que os inteiro e a string em questão são correspondentes imprima o seguinte: `System.out.printf("%s - String: %s, int: %d\n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), valorrpm, valorrpmint);`.

Comment: Se eu colocar as duas variaveis declaras junta no while uma atrapalha a outra, exemplo, se coloco valorrpm = arduino6.getPeso(); valorromint = Integer.parseInt(valorrpm) nem a variavel valorrpm printa mais

Comment: Ficou a mesma coisa Anthony, joguei para uma thread e da o seguinte erro:     WARNING:  RXTX Version mismatch
 Jar version = RXTX-2.2pre1
 native lib Version = RXTX-2.2pre2
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "750

"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at tanio.RunObterRpm.run(RunObterRpm.java:20)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ///Ele recebe corretamente  o valor em input String

Comment: porem nao consegue fazer a conversao? sera pq? preciso converter para comparar o valor do rpm para saber se o motor ligou, if (valorrpmint > 0 ){carro ligou}else{carro nao ligou}, tem cmo fazer essa comparacao sem converter?

Comment: `"750 "`. Parece que tem um espaço em branco no fim da sua `String`. Tente usar `Integer.parseInt(valorrpm.trim());` Se funcionar eu transformo em resposta.

Comment: Anthony, tentei mas deu excessao Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at tanio.RunObterRpm.run(RunObterRpm.java:20)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748), nullpointer e excessao de nao receber nada, porem a variavel sem conversao printa normalmente, sera que nao ha outra forma de conversão?

Comment: Você poderia incluir o código da classe `SerialVirtualCom3`?

Comment: Weslley ta ai, desconsidera algumas partes que estao entre os /*, tava tentando tratar as excessoes mas acabei desistindo

Comment: Tente setar a sua variável `peso` em uma nova String. Algo como `String str = arduino6.getPeso();`. Após isso, jogue o `str` no output.

Comment: Mas nao e isso que ja estou fazendo com String valorrpm = arduino6.getPeso(); Nao intendo porque esta conversao nao funciona, ou quando parece que vai funcionar da excessao. Estou achando que deverei entao ter que no metodo de leitura do buffer para me retornar o inteiro em vez do string

Answer (score 0):

Basta substituir o '%s' por '%d'.

O '%s' serve para a impressão de Strings e o '%d' serve para impressão de valores inteiros.

```
chamarTelaPrincipal.rpm.setText(String.format("%d", valorrpmint));
```

Comment: Se explicar o porquê acho que a resposta ficaria melhor e completa.

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão.