# Converter String para Inteiro em Android

Tags: android, string

Galera, ja tinha aberto uma pergunta referente a esse assunto mas em java([Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/243020/retorno-inesperado-ao-converter-string-para-inteiro-no-java)), nao consegui resolver e agora num apk android estou com o Mesmo Problema.

Tenho um servico com uma thread rodando um servidor socket, nele usando ResultReceiver jogo a informação para um textview, essas informacoes são String's de um cliente java no pc, para efeito de manipular esses dados recebidos usando um switch quero converter a String para um inteiro(Se tiver outra forma de fazer...).

Porem na conversao usando o metodo parseInt a aplicacao da erro, Adianto que estou programando de um pc com menos de 1gb de ram, nao da pra abrir o emulador tao pouco ver o log de erros. Alem do mais como e conexao socket o emulador andoid do eclipse nao tem a capacidade de emular wifi.
Sei que foi erro na hora de converter pois comentei esse trecho  e  o programa rodou normal.

Não sei se esta e a maneira correta de manipular os dados recebidos, mas creio que nao atrapalha nada a thread principal;

Se alguem poder testar e ver o porque da conversao não ser bem sucedida, ou se alguem ja sabe o problema olhando o codigo e poder identificar, os codigos estao a seguir:

Aqui e a classe servico que roda a thread com o servidor socket

```
package com.example.palioteste;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.ResultReceiver;

public class ServidorSocketIntent extends IntentService{

    public int porta = 9955;
    public Socket conexao;
    public boolean ativo;
    public String clientSentence;
    private ResultReceiver rr;


    public ServidorSocketIntent() {

        super("ServidorSocketIntentThread");

        ativo = true;
        clientSentence = "";

    }



    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){


     rr = intent.getParcelableExtra("receiver");

   return(super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId));
    }



    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {


        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = null;
           try {
            welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(porta);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

while (ativo) {
    try{   

  Socket connectionSocket = null;
        conexao = welcomeSocket.accept();


   BufferedReader inFromClient = null;

    inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( conexao.getInputStream() ));

    clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();

    //clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();

    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("resposta", clientSentence);

    rr.send(1, b);

    } catch(Exception e ){

    } 

    try {
        conexao.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


    }

}
```

Aqui o MainActivity:

```
package com.example.palioteste;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.ResultReceiver;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ServiceConnection{

        private ServiceConnection connection;    
        private RespostaCliente respostafinal;
        private ImageButton imageButtonLigar;
        private ImageButton imageButtonDesligar;
        static TextView feedback;
        private  ResultReceiverListener rr;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       connection = this;



       imageButtonLigar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonLigar);

        imageButtonDesligar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonDesligar);

        feedback = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.feedback);


        imageButtonLigar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {


        abrirSocket rodar = new abrirSocket("2");
                rodar.execute();

                imageButtonLigar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                imageButtonDesligar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);        
            }

        });



        imageButtonDesligar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {



                abrirSocket rodar = new abrirSocket("3");
                rodar.execute();

                imageButtonLigar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageButtonDesligar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  
            }

        });

        //bindService(new Intent("Socket_Resposta"),connection , Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);//Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE
        //inicia o servico binder para obter conexao com a thread rodando dentro do servico

          startService();





    }





    public void startService(){

        rr = null;
        rr = new ResultReceiverListener(null);


        Intent it = new Intent ("Socket_RespostaIntent");
        it.putExtra("receiver", rr);

        startService(it);

        }


    public void stopService (View view){
        Intent it = new Intent ("Socket_RespostaIntent");
        stopService(it);
        it.putExtra("desligar", 1);
        startService(it);

    }

    /*public void startService(View view){
        Intent it = new Intent("Servico_Teste");
        startService(it);
    }
    */


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }






    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }




    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {

    }


    private class ResultReceiverListener extends ResultReceiver{
          public ResultReceiverListener(Handler handler) {
            super(handler);
        }

    @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultcode, Bundle bundle){

           if (resultcode == 1){
           final String resposta = bundle.getString("resposta");

        //metodo que recebe a resposta e atualiza a ui
           runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
          public void run(){
             // feedback.setText("Resposta do Cliente: "+ resposta);
               int respostaint = Integer.parseInt(resposta);

          switch(respostaint){

         case 1:
            feedback.setText("O resultado e 1");
            \\executa outros metodos             

           break;

         case 2:
           feedback.setText("Resposta 2");
          \\executa outras funcoes
           break;
```

}

```
          }
                    });
                }
        }


    }



}
```

Aqui o Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.palioteste"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:label="ServidorSocket" android:name="ServidorSocket">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <action android:name="Socket_Resposta"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:label="ServidorSocketIntent" android:name="ServidorSocketIntent">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <action android:name="Socket_RespostaIntent"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro verifique se a string não está nula, pois isso causara um erro, já que não existe número vazio. Depois faça a conversão dentro de um try para poder fazer tratamentos:

```
if(sNum!=null)
  try {
   int num = Integer.parseInt(sNum)
 }
 catch(NumberFormatException e){
   //Log.i();
 }
```

Comment: && !sNum.equals("")

Comment: Também, se precisar

Comment: Obrigado pelo contato gente, ja tinha testado estes metodos ate em Java, porem nao funcionaram, curioso e que por exemplo, no java ao usar parseInt, nao a nenhum erro no log, porem o resultado nao e o esperado https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/243020/retorno-inesperado-ao-converter-string-para-inteiro-no-java. No Android tambem nao ha nenhum erro na compilação, porem o resultado nao e o correto, vejam agora aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/243794/ler-inteiro-com-bufferedreader-em-android.

Comment: Pra esclarecer usando apenas x != null o valor retornado e sempre zero(0), usando != null e !x.equals("") resultado e nulo nao aparece nada. nos dois casos coloquei uma else if (x == null) z = 0000; mesmo assim resutado foi zero(0) em vez dos 0000

Comment: Se z é um int, 0000 é igual a zero e um sysout de z seria 0.

Comment: Ja consegui resolver, no cliente socket java para a saida usei write(byte), e no servidor socket usei read(), desse modo nao foi necessario nenhuma conversao, no client socket usar writeInt() nao resolveu.

Answer (score 0):

O melhor é usar uma lib da google que é guava.

Git
https://github.com/google/guava

Para adiciona:

`dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.guava:guava:23.1-jre'
  // or, for Android:
  compile 'com.google.guava:guava:23.1-android'
}`

Assim para fazer essa conversão basta:

```
Integer tryParse(String string)
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
Integer number = Ints.tryParse("23");
```

Não sendo necessário validações de null, vazios e possíveis exception.

Comment: A validação de `null` será necessária já que `tryParse()` retornará `null` caso a conversão não seja possível.

Comment: Estava-me a referir ao input.