# Ler Inteiro com BufferedReader em Android

Tags: java, android, buffer, inteiros

Numa Aplicacao Android, tenho um cliente socket java que envia inteiros(usando writeInt) para um servidor socket no Android que estou tentando ler estes inteiros. Recebo strings corretamentes porem nao consiguo converter ao usar parseInt, [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/243020/retorno-inesperado-ao-converter-string-para-inteiro-no-java) e [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/243414/converter-string-para-inteiro-em-android).

Neste pedaco do codigo tento fazer a leitura usando read(), porem sempre retorna zero, traduzi os diversos reader que contem retorno inteiro mas nao consegui intender, se alguem com experiencia poder ajudar e dizer qual metodo e usado para ler o inteiro...

```
conexao = welcomeSocket.accept();



    BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( conexao.getInputStream() ));

    clientSentence = inFromClient.read(); //retorna zero


    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt("resposta", clientSentence);

    rr.send(1, b);

    } catch(Exception e ){

    }
```

Comment: Lendo essa sua pergunta, e as outras duas, acho que era melhor você disponibilizar seu projeto, ou uma parte que possa ser executada (e.g. no github), para que a gente possa tentar reproduzir o problema.

Comment: Articuno, na verdade nessa pergunta aqui : https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/243414/converter-string-para-inteiro-em-android/243416#243416 ; eu peço alguem para testar o codigo: "Se alguem poder testar e ver o porque da conversao não ser bem sucedida, ou se alguem ja sabe o problema olhando o codigo e poder identificar, os codigos estao a seguir", entao... Outra coisa voce saberia qual metodo de leitura usar para ler diretamente o inteiro, no metodo read da classe bufferedReader nao intendi bem, A conversao da string recebida so retorna zero ou nada, isso que tentei por ultimo,